# How to debug the Angular error "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page"?

Tags: gulp, protractor

```
**..\..\node_modules\gulp-angular-protractor\node_modules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\nexttick.js:41
  goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
                                      ^
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"**
```

What could be the possible error in the code?

Comment: Did you try googling? Let us know what you tried so far and we can help better ,.... Right now  its only a guessing game ..

Comment: Sync Issues:
put : `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`

Comment: I tried, downgrading the selenium server standalone - 3.3.1 to 2.53.0. But no luck. And another thing i tried is, putting browser.waitForAngular().

Comment: Thanks @KishanPatel - I think it is working.

Comment: @AshutoshAnshu .. Just trying to understand the root cause .. is yours a non-angular site? ..

Comment: No, It's angularJS.

Comment: There is not enough information to help solve this problem. Please provide: browser version, protractor configuration file, node version, binaries (drivers and selenium standalone server), the spec that is causing this problem. Also could be important: how your angular page is bootstrapped and where you load angular in your index.html. Simply providing a stacktrace is not enough. Please go back and revise your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason would be the loading page, since you are trying to search in the Angular Page and the result page would be Angular too. But the page in between them for eg:  when you click some thing that would open another page, in between the opening you will get some loading screen or the loader icon etc. That may not be Angular. So you are getting synchronization issues.

Normally we will get there errors in loaders, frames or video contents in the Angular pages.

Try using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` and once you page got Angular page got loaded make the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;`
So that the actual testcases for the Angular page will not fail.